# Tree display hw, hw.cpp & hw.cpp2 in sub-directories

Tags: tree

I would like `tree` to display the hw files in the sub-directories like this:

```
.
├── exp
│   └── hw
├── src
│   └── hw.cpp2
└── tmp
    └── hw.cpp
```

`$ /usr/bin/tree --noreport  .` displays all of the files:

```
.
├── exp
│   ├── hi
│   └── hw
├── src
│   ├── hi.cpp2
│   └── hw.cpp2
├── ssbuild.bash
├── sslogin.bash
└── tmp
    ├── hi.cpp
    └── hw.cpp
```

`/usr/bin/tree --noreport -P *hw .` gets `hw` w/o an extension:

```
.
├── exp
│   └── hw
├── src
└── tmp
```

`/usr/bin/tree --noreport -P hw* .` produces:

```
.
├── exp
├── src
└── tmp
```

Version info `/usr/bin/tree --version`:

```
tree v2.1.0 © 1996 - 2022 by Steve Baker, Thomas Moore, Francesc Rocher, Florian Sesser, Kyosuke Tokoro
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tree` utility has a specific option, `-P`, for specifying a pattern that the filenames must match to be part of the output.  The type of pattern used with `-P` is a shell filename globbing pattern, and as such, it needs to be quoted to avoid having the shell expand it on the command line.

```bash
tree -P 'hw*' .
```

Since your current directory doesn't contain any name matching `*hw` (and since you are using a shell that does not complain about non-matching globbing patterns, like `zsh` would do by default, and like `bash` would do with its `failglob` shell option set), the pattern wasn't expanded when you tried to use it.  However, that pattern only matches names that *end* in the string `hw`. I can however not explain why you get that output when using `hw*` on the command line.

Example:

```bash
$ tree .
.
├── exp
│   ├── hi
│   └── hw
├── src
│   ├── hi.cpp2
│   └── hw.cpp2
├── ssbuild.bash
├── sslogin.bash
└── tmp
    ├── hi.cpp
    └── hw.cpp

3 directories, 8 files
```

```bash
$ tree -P 'hw*' .
.
├── exp
│   └── hw
├── src
│   └── hw.cpp2
└── tmp
    └── hw.cpp

3 directories, 3 files
```